# Istanbul-Belgrade, Serbia

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, turkey

I will be shortly travelling to Belgrade, Serbia via Istanbul, Turkey. I have a stop over of 1 hour 35 minutes duration. Do I require an e-visa for this purpose?

Comment: You forgot to mention about your nationality.

Comment: @Hatef Unless it's on separate tickets, OP doesn't Need one regardless

Answer (score 3):

If your trip is in one booking, then as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=TR&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

Otherwise, it depends on what passport you hold.

Answer (score 1):

That depends:

- If you booked it as single journey. You will just go to next flight. There should be a security check too. No passport control!
- If you booked it separately. Then,

  - If you dont have a checked-in luggage, just consult to transit desk they will provide you the ticket for the next flight and you go to gate via the transit area.
  - If you have a checked-in luggage, you need to pass custom which means you need e-visa and 1 h 35 mins will not be enough to pass control, take luggage, check-in again and go through the pass control and security again.